# How to send a mail message using Indy's smtp server component?

Tags: delphi, indy

Since the demo given in http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Demos/index.EN.aspx only saves the received stream to a file, I don't know how to effectevely send that stream as a mail.

Could anyone teach me how to do this or to point me some more complete example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A SMTP *server* component can't send mail - it can only receive it. You need a SMTP *client* component (TidSMTP) to send mail. A mail server when it sends mail acts like an SMTP client.

Comment: To expand on that, Indy has a TIdSMTPRelay component that is meant to be used on the server end to forward received emails to other servers.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a complete example on how to send an email:

```
VAR SMTP : TIdSMTP;
VAR MSG : TIdMSG;
.
.
  MSG:=TIdMSG.Create(NIL);
  TRY
    WITH MSG.Recipients.Add DO BEGIN
      Name:='<Name of recipient>';
      Address:='<Email address of recipient>'
    END;
    MSG.BccList.Add.Address:='<Email address of Blind Copy recipient>';
    MSG.From.Name:='<Name of sender>';
    MSG.From.Address:='<Email address of sender>';
    MSG.Body.Text:='<Message Body>';
    MSG.Subject:='<Subject of message>';
    SMTP:=TIdSMTP.Create(NIL);
    TRY
      SMTP.Host:='x.x.x.x'; // IP Address of SMTP server
      SMTP.Port:=25; // Port address of SMTP service (usually 25)
      SMTP.Connect;
      TRY
        SMTP.Send(MSG)
      FINALLY
        SMTP.Disconnect
      END
    FINALLY
      SMTP.Free
    END
  FINALLY
    MSG.Free
  END;
.
.
```

(I know that WITH is frowned upon, but I generally use it in instances like this where there's no doubt as to what is going on, and where there's no (or just an infinitesimal) chance of ambiguity)

Comment: Wow - this code screams. I'd convert most of it to mixed-case or lowercase to make it friendlier for the eyes of most Delphi developers.