# How to immediately send mail without prompt confirmation dialog

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, mapi

I'm using Delphi XE3 and below is my sample application:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    function Send(const FromAddr, ToAddr, Subject: String; const AttachFiles: array
        of string; const MsgBody: String): boolean;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses Winapi.Mapi;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Send('', 'lmengyew@gmail.com', 'test', [], '');
end;

function TForm1.Send(const FromAddr, ToAddr, Subject: String; const
    AttachFiles: array of string; const MsgBody: String): boolean;
var Msg: TMapiMessage;
    lpSender, lpRecipient: TMapiRecipDesc;
    Attach: array of TMapiFileDesc;
    SMTP: TFNMapiSendMail;
    MAPIModule: HModule;
    i: integer;
    S: string;
begin
  Result := False;
  FillChar(Msg, SizeOf(Msg), 0);

  Msg.lpszSubject := PAnsiChar(UTF8String(Subject));
  Msg.lpszNoteText := PAnsiChar(UTF8String(MsgBody));

  if FromAddr <> '' then begin
    lpSender.ulRecipClass := MAPI_ORIG;
    lpSender.lpszName     := PAnsiChar(UTF8String(FromAddr));
    lpSender.lpszAddress  := PAnsiChar(UTF8String(FromAddr));
    lpSender.ulReserved   := 0;
    lpSender.ulEIDSize    := 0;
    lpSender.lpEntryID    := Nil;
    Msg.lpOriginator      := @lpSender;
  end;

  if ToAddr <> '' then begin
    lpRecipient.ulRecipClass := MAPI_TO;
    lpRecipient.lpszName     := PAnsiChar(UTF8String(ToAddr));
    lpRecipient.lpszAddress  := PAnsiChar(UTF8String(ToAddr));
    lpRecipient.ulReserved   := 0;
    lpRecipient.ulEIDSize    := 0;
    lpRecipient.lpEntryID    := Nil;
    Msg.nRecipCount          := 1;
    Msg.lpRecips             := @lpRecipient;
  end;

  SetLength(Attach, Length(AttachFiles));
  FillChar(Attach[0], Length(Attach) * SizeOf(TMapiFileDesc), 0);
  i := 0;
  for S in AttachFiles do begin
    Attach[i].nPosition := Cardinal($FFFFFFFF);
    Attach[i].lpszPathName := PAnsiChar(UTF8String(S));
    Inc(i);
  end;
  Msg.nFileCount := Length(AttachFiles);

  if Msg.nFileCount = 0 then
    Msg.lpFiles := nil
  else
    Msg.lpFiles := @Attach[0];

  MAPIModule := LoadLibrary(PChar(MAPIDLL));

  if MAPIModule <> 0 then begin
    try
      @SMTP := GetProcAddress(MAPIModule, 'MAPISendMail');
      if @SMTP <> nil then
        Result := SMTP(0, Application.Handle, Msg, 0, 0) = SUCCESS_SUCCESS;
    finally
      FreeLibrary(MAPIModule);
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

[image]

When i click the Button1, it will prompt the confirmation dialog as print screen. My question is how to immediate send mail without prompt the confirmation dialog? Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

It's easy. Don't use `MAPI`. :-)

Sending mail via `MAPI` without user intervention is what malware/spyware does, so Windows blocks it to prevent that from happening. You can't bypass that security, because it's been added specifically to prevent you from doing so.

Imagine if you could, and you were writing something bad. You could scan the users computer, grab any files you wanted (like financial documents, personal information, and so forth), and email them anywhere without the users permission. Or you could just start sending out viruses and spam from the users email account. Oops! You're doing exactly what used to happen, which is exactly why the user is now asked about sending email via `MAPI`.

You can have the user configure their outgoing account for your software, and then use `TIdSMTP` (or any other SMTP component) to send mail via that account. This allows the user to acknowledge that your application will be sending mail, and provide any credentials (server name, email account) and security information (user name, password, etc.) needed for email.

Comment: It IS possible though with Extended MAPI... See Outlook Redemption for an example http://www.dimastr.com

Comment: Let's be clear here - the OP is using *Simple* MAPI. If you were using *Extended* MAPI, there'd be no prompts. But Extended MAPI is only supported by the real Outlook, not Outlook Express or Windows Live Mail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. In your code you're using MAPI - you have to drop that approach and use some of SMTP components that exist for Delphi. I can recommend you two:

**Indy (IdSMTP)** - comes with Delphi, example of usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440911/how-to-send-a-mail-message-using-indys-smtp-server-component)

**Overbyte ICS (SmtpCli)** - site [here](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html), and for example of usage look at the `MailSnd` demo in `Samples\Delphi\MailNewsDemos` directory once you install components.